# Difference between localhost and production

Tags: django, authentication

I have this statement on localhost

```
If self.request.user.is_authenticated:
```

And when I am not logged in it does not enter, but in production if it enters

Do you know why the difference?

UPDATE:
After testing several things, reboot guicorn and nothing, then restart the server and I run, I guess I was working with something in cache, it's what I can think of

Comment: This statement is not dependent on localhost or production. On both of them it will work same

Comment: But exactly the same code is working in different ways

Comment: What Django version are you using in development and production?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't depend on a production or localhost, it works the same on both - it just checks whether the user, which made a request, is authenticated.